# How to upload audio files with express backend and react-native?

Tags: typescript, react-native

when I try to upload audio files in my react-native project, it seems no Filelist in react-native , so I can't upload file , any one could help? thx~

```
interface IAudioInputs {
  readers_id: number;
  level_type_id?: number;
  books_id: number;
  page_num_id: number;
  recording_data: FileList | string  ;
}
```

Comment: share your code snippet. what you have done so far.

Comment: just set the interface for  recording_data: FileList | string  ; and it shows Cannot find name 'FileList'.ts(2304)

Comment: please share your upload codes etc.

Comment: but just these codes already shown error as I mentioned

Answer (score 0):

you can upload audio file like this example

```
async function uploadAudioAsync(uri) {
  console.log("Uploading " + uri);
  let apiUrl = 'http://YOUR_SERVER_HERE/upload';
  let uriParts = uri.split('.');
  let fileType = uriParts[uriParts.length - 1];

  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', {
    uri,
    name: `recording.${fileType}`,
    type: `audio/x-${fileType}`,
  });

  let options = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
  };

  console.log("POSTing " + uri + " to " + apiUrl);
  return fetch(apiUrl, options);
}

// Do a recording
let uri = await this.recording.getURI();
await uploadAudioAsync(uri);
```

Comment: sorry I am new in coding, because I can set interface with type File and FileList in my react project, so is it in react-native, I can't use the same method to upload files? thx

Comment: I mean in my previous react-project,  I can upload file with Multer , File type, but now in my react-native project, I can't upload files like  what I did in react~

Comment: you can use above mentioned code snippet for react native.

Comment: thx @Muhammad,  but could you explain why File | FileList is not exist in react-native?